# Gradle doesn't build - class DefaultTaskInputPropertyRegistration cannot be cast to class TaskInputs

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, build.gradle, java-11

A project was using gradle wrapper 4.6 and I had to updated it to 5.0 because my pc has java 11 installed.

When using gradlew 4.6 with java 8 build was ok.

After upgrading to 5.0 and running it with java 11 (both gradle wrapper 5.0 and installed gradle 6.5) keeps throwing the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\MyProject\build.gradle' line: 52

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my_project'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.gradle.java']
   > Could not create task ':api:compileJava'.
      > class org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputPropertyRegistration cannot be cast to class org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskInputs (org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputPropertyRegistration and org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskInputs are in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @26653222)
```

The line in build.gradle that is generating the error is

```
configure(subprojects - [project(':event')]) { subProject ->
    apply plugin: 'java' // <= this line 52
    apply plugin: ...
    ...
}
```

It is a multiproject gradle project and build.gradle is the root

It doesn't matter which gradle command or task I run, I keep getting the same error.

**UPDATE**
Works with gradle up to 4.10. 5.0 starts failing.

https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html says

> The Java Library Distribution Plugin is now based on the Java Library Plugin  instead of the Java Plugin.
> While it applies the Java Plugin, it behaves slightly different (e.g. it adds > the API configuration). Thus, make sure to check whether your build behaves as expected after upgrading.

Still don't know what it means and what I'm supposed to do with that

**UPDATE 2 *(Laksitha Ranasingha comment)***
Tried in gradle 5.0, build.gradle rewriting the plugins definition:

```
configure(subprojects - [project(':event')]) { subProject ->
    plugins { // <= line 52
        id 'java' 
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Results in the following error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>   Build file 'C:\MyProjects\build.gradle' line: 52
> - What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myproject'.
>
> > Could not find method plugins() for arguments [build_1pjmxtxk8zv5w7chejrs1s08b$_run_closure2$_closure7@73b72d7e] on project ':api' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
>
> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
> Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
> See https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> CONFIGURE FAILED in 0s

Comment: You are trying to `apply` core `java` plugin old-style way. Can you try 
`plugins {  id 'java' }`
More info https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha unfortunately, that didn't work either. I updated my question with your sugestion

Comment: @aee Have you been able to resolve this issue? I'm having the exact same problem trying to upgrade gradle from 4.10.2 to 5.0.

Comment: @Allix unfortunately no. I can only use gradle versions lower than 5.0. You can find the migration steps in https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html if that helps but I couldn't solve it yet.